# git as the book said but error occur

Tags: git

1.I just create and initialized a folder and make it a repository, and add 2 folder which are in it. I commit them together by once. Then I add the remote repository, but when I begin to push it, error come out: here is the code I made and the error below:

```
git init
git add 2048-personal
git add canvas-time-counter
git commit
git remote add origin git@github.com:CharlesLN/front_end.git
git push -u origin master
```

Then the error come out:

```
To git@github.com:CharlesLN/front_end.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:CharlesLN/front_end.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

then I keyed `git pull`
then the info:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From github.com:CharlesLN/front_end
*[new branch] master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

Then I keyed `git pull remote`:

```
fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then `git status`

So, I don't know where is wrong and who can tell me the problem?
Thank you!

I have tried over 3 times and it's still the same wrong! please give me some help, thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should do

```
git pull origin master
```

You need to get everything from github, which is your origin.

When vim opens, press i and write a short message and then press escape. To save the message press

```
:wq
```

Which means write and quit. After that you should be able to do that push.

Comment: but it come out with a window that let me to enter commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,...but I don't know how to get back to the commond window

Comment: Write a message and save and ecit the editor. Which text editor are you using with git?

Comment: vim I think, but I think the important thing is that I can't push it.